# É possível mostrar mensagem de exceção em pt-BR?

Tags: c#, .net, string, exceção, localização

Gostaria que minhas mensagem de exceção fossem mostradas em português, alguém saberia como?

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Debug.Writeline(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Além de não ser bom capturar `Exception` eu falo sobre isto em [várias perguntas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:101%20[exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o]), o ideal é fazer algo útil quando captura uma exceção. Mostrar o texto bruto da exceção para o usuário não costuma ser considerado algo muito útil. Em geral estas mensagens são feitas para informar ao programador e não ao usuário.

Se ainda quiser fazer isto, mude a cultura da *thread*:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

Se o Windows não tiver os pacotes em português instalados, então fica mais complicado, teria que fazer manualmente.

Veja [**não** funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wfVdxz). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uA0gTZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Culture/Messages.cs). Mas veja a forma de testar se deu certo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, quando você se refere a "não ser bom capturar" `exception`, se refere somente as genéricas ou qualquer uma, por exemplo, as específicas como `FileNotFoundException `?

Comment: As genéricas. Embora dependendo do contexto qualquer exceção pode ser genérica :) O que precisa é capturar a mais específica possível. Até eventualmente pode ser a `Exception`, mas só vejo um caso para fazer isto.

Comment: Realmente a própria documentação não recomenda CA1031: Do not catch general exception types (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx )